# At 10k rep, can you flag still?

Tags: discussion, flagging, 10k-tools

Once you reach 10k rep, which I think is where you can review flags, can you flag or not? Because it seems pretty silly if you can...

Comment: You can still not review moderator flags. Besides... why don't you just earn those missing 9073 points and find it out? ;-)

Comment: That might take a while.

Comment: read answer again now...  ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you would still have the ability to flag when you hit 10k, *however*, the system does not allow you to review your own flags.

Comment: Umm... I can still flag stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Reviewing flags is mostly a privilege gained by winning a moderator election – and not by reputation. There once was a flag queue for 10 k users but it was abolished a few years ago.

The only exceptions are:

- not-an-answer and very-low-quality flags, which send posts to the low-quality queue, where you can review with 2 k reputation;
- close flags, which send questions to the close queue, where you can review with 3 k reputation.

The only privilege related to flag handling that you gain afterwards is that your deletion decisions in the low-quality queue have a stronger impact once you reached 20 k reputation.

Either way, you cannot handle your own flags or flags on your own posts.